# Changing jquery values on window resize

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```js
$(".slick-slider-view").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
```

I need the value of 'slidesToShow to change to 2 when the window width is less than 1000px:

```js
    $(".slick-slider-view").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
```

How can I use @media like feature with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this example from the slick plugin doc:

```
$(".slider").slick({

  // normal options...
  infinite: false,

  // the magic
  responsive: [{

      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        infinite: true
      }

    }, {

      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        dots: true
      }

    }, {

      breakpoint: 300,
      settings: "unslick" // destroys slick

    }]
});
```

The plugin has a responsive feature just for that.

Ref: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

```js
const media = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');

media.addListener((mql) => {
  console.log(window.innerWidth);
});
```